# .out file acting strange, delimiter wont register until file is saved in wordpad after making no changes

Tags: java

I am trying to create an output file that we can upload to another program. This file has the delimiter "|". So for example, in the file will be

```
id|phone|lastname|firstname|code|code|code|code|
id|phone|lastname|firstname|code|code|code|code|
id|phone|lastname|firstname|code|code|code|code|
```

The strange thing is, when I output the file and upload it, only the first string is registered. BUT If I open the .out file in wordpad and SIMPLY CLICK SAVE (make no changes, just press the button) and then upload the file, it will register all strings listed. I am having to manually go in and save all of these files before uploading them and there has to be a very simple reason why the wordpad save changes it. I checked the hex and all characters are the exact same before and after the save. I've searched and searched, I just have no idea where to even begin solving this problem

Comment: Did you try and reproduce this on another machine? Are the files otherwise uploaded automatically instead of manually? In batch instead of one-by-one?

Comment: The underlying thought here is that if the hex is the same, the file can not have changed, hence the problem must be somewhere else, eg the uploading process or the machine.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with line break characters maybe. Can you look at the whitespace before and after saving with Wordpad?